# How to convert Bundler's bundle.out format into Meshlab's project format (.mlp)

Tags: python, meshlab

I am using MeshLab for processing 3D scans, and in particular for giving the mesh a texture.
I am attempting to automate some of Meshlab's features using the command line, and meshlabserver works well for some tasks. However, I am using the bundle.out format for storing camera positions, and there doesn't seem to be an option for opening a bundle.out file using meshlabserver. I need to get the camera positions from my 3D scan in order to apply the texture.

I have tried converting the data in the bundle.out file into an .mlp file using a Python script, by opening the two respective files and comparing the formatting within, but in the process of writing the script, I noticed that the two files don't contain exactly the same data, even for the same camera. In particular, the translation vector contained within the bundle.out file does not match the translation vector in the .mlp file.

Here is a sample from the .mlp file that I created in MeshLab by importing a bundle.out file:

```
<!DOCTYPE MeshLabDocument>
<MeshLabProject>
 <MeshGroup/>
 <RasterGroup>
  <MLRaster label="IMG_1923.JPG">
   <VCGCamera TranslationVector="1.47497 -1.02971 3.11087 1" LensDistortion="0 0" CameraType="0" PixelSizeMm="1 1" ViewportPx="4032 3024" CenterPx="2016 1512" RotationMatrix="0.874226 0.050346 -0.482903 0 0.0346906 -0.998544 -0.0413029 0 -0.484279 0.0193558 -0.8747 0 0 0 0 1 " FocalMm="3345.59"/>
   <Plane semantic="1" fileName="images/IMG_1923.JPG"/>
  </MLRaster>
...
```

Notice the "TranslationVector" attribute, and the values within it.

Here is the bundle.out file that was used to create the .mlp file:

```
# Bundle file v0.3
91 4888
3345.59 0.0177087 0
0.874226 0.050346 -0.482903
0.0346906 -0.998544 -0.0413029
-0.484279 0.0193558 -0.8747
-0.264628 0.950892 -3.4553
...
```

The bundle file should be interpreted as follows:

```
# Bundle file v0.3
<number of images> <number of points>
<f> <k1> <k2>
<r_1,1> <r_1,2> <r_1,3>
<r_2,1> <r_2,2> <r_2,3>
<r_3,1> <r_3,2> <r_3,3>
<t_1> <t_2> <t_3>
...
```

where:
f: focal length
k1 and k2: radial distortion coefficients
r_i,j: elements of the rotation matrix
t_i: element of translation vector

The three values t_1, t_2 and t_3 on the last line is where the translation vector is stored. It does not match that of the .mlp file. All the other values that are common to both files match.

A link to the bundle.out file format specification: http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~snavely/bundler/bundler-v0.3-manual.html#S6
(Scroll down to "VI. Output format and scene representation")

I expected that the .mlp file would contain the same information about the cameras and rasters as the bundle.out file, but one attribute, the translation vector, does not match in both files.

It would be helpful if someone could explain why there is a difference, and possibly provide a means of transforming the vector in the bundle.out file into that of the .mlp file.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

After digging through MeshLab's source code, I came across this file:
https://github.com/cnr-isti-vclab/meshlab/blob/d596d7c086c51fbdfb56050f9c30b55dd0286d4c/src/meshlabplugins/filter_layer/filter_layer.cpp

From line 630:

```
//// Import cameras
for (uint i = 0; i < num_cams; ++i)
{
    float f, k1, k2;
    float R[16] = { 0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,1 };
    vcg::Point3f t;

    fgets(line, 100, fp);; if (line[0] == '\0') return false; sscanf(line, "%f %f %f", &f, &k1, &k2);

    fgets(line, 100, fp);; if (line[0] == '\0') return false; sscanf(line, "%f %f %f", &(R[0]), &(R[1]), &(R[2]));  R[3] = 0;
    fgets(line, 100, fp);; if (line[0] == '\0') return false; sscanf(line, "%f %f %f", &(R[4]), &(R[5]), &(R[6]));  R[7] = 0;
    fgets(line, 100, fp);; if (line[0] == '\0') return false; sscanf(line, "%f %f %f", &(R[8]), &(R[9]), &(R[10])); R[11] = 0;

    fgets(line, 100, fp);; if (line[0] == '\0') return false; sscanf(line, "%f %f %f", &(t[0]), &(t[1]), &(t[2]));

    Matrix44f mat = Matrix44f::Construct(Matrix44f(R));

    Matrix33f Rt = Matrix33f(Matrix44f(mat), 3);
    Rt.Transpose();

    Point3f pos = Rt * Point3f(t[0], t[1], t[2]);

    md.rasterList[i]->shot.Extrinsics.SetTra(Point3f(-pos[0], -pos[1], -pos[2]));
...
}
```

This is where the transformation from Bundler's translation vector to Meshlab's translation vector occurs.

The information I extracted from the code above was as follows:

Recipe for transforming translation vector from bundle.out to .mlp:

1. read rotation matrix (from bundle.out), store as R
2. read translation vector (from bundle.out), store as t
3. transpose rotation matrix R
4. Multiply R-transposed by t, store as pos
5. set pos as the .mlp translation vector

I tested this recipe in Python, and the output is the same as in the .mlp file